# How to document destructured parameters in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation, jsdoc

```
async function userInformation({ userId, token }) {
  const body = {
    user: userId
  };

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  };

  const url = 'https://example.com/api/users';

  const data = await axios.post(url, headers, qs.stringify(body));

  return data;
}
```

Consider this code
How should I write jsdoc for this function ?
How to ensure that the parameters types were defined in jsdoc ?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have destructured your parameters, they still came from one source (an object) which is what you need to document.

I'd recommend using `@typedef` to describe the shape of the object and use it as a type when documenting your function.

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} Credentials
 * @property {number} userId
 * @property {string} token
 */

/**
 * @param {Credentials} credentials
 */
async function userInformation({ userId, token }) {
  // ...
}
```

Here's a screencast from VS Code showing that it can interpret this doc block. (I'm sure other IDEs can do the same)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work perfectly, as it's an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24746) but the best you can do is:

```js
/**
 * @param {{ userId: number, token: string }} info
 * @param {string} info.userId this description appears
 * @param {number} info.token this also appears on hover
 */
async function userInformation({ userId, token }) {
  const body = {
    user: userId
  };

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  };

  const url = 'https://example.com/api/users';

  const data = await axios.post(url, headers, qs.stringify(body));

  return data;
}
```

You end up writing information twice, but it seems to make sure VSCode knows whats going on.